# Summation of an infinite series $\frac{x}{4^x}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, summation

I've found by the ratio test that the following series is convergent, however I am struggling to find the value of the sum. Could anyone suggest where to go from here to find the sum?

$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{i}{4^i} = $

Thanks in advance.

PS - This is the answer via [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+x%2F4%5Ex+from+0+to+infinity)

Comment: This is an arithematico-geometric series see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico-geometric_sequence

Comment: @JonathanRichardLombardy From your link, would my a = 0, r = 1/4 and d = 1?

Comment: the first term is $0$ start with $ i=1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**METHODOLOGY $1$:**  With Calculus

Let $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$.  For $|x|<1$, the geometric series converges to $f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$.

Note that the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^{n-1}$, formed by differentiating term-by-term, converges uniformly for all $|x|\le r<1$.

Since the series representation for $f(x)$ converges, then we have $f'(x)=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^{n-1}$ for all $|x|<1$.   Hence, we have $\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^n=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$

Now, letting $x=\frac14$, we find

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n}{4^n}=\frac{1/4}{(1-(1/4))^2}=\frac{4}{9}$$

---

**METHODOLOGY $2$:**  Without Calculus

Note that we can write

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^n&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n\sum_{m=1}^{n}(1)\\\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{n=m}^{\infty}x^n\\\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{x^m}{1-x} \\\\
&=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Hi @Dr. MV thanks for your comment. I ran the equation through [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+x%2F4%5Ex+from+0+to+infinity) and found the answer to be 4/9, which is different than your own.

Comment: @zcoon Good catch.  Yes, I've edited to correct the errata. -Mark

Comment: Is there a more general name for the methodology 1 you used?

Comment: @zcoon In the first approach, we merely differentiated under the summation, which is valid since the series of term-by-term derivatives converges uniformly for $|x|\le r<1$ (and the original series converges for at least on point).

Comment: @Dr. MV There is a little typo in your first derivation. The first instance of $f'(x)$ has the $x$ squared instead of the the whole denominator.

Comment: @FofX Thank you for the catch!  Much appreciated.  I've edited.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let's integrate 
$$\int \frac{x}{4^x}dx=\frac{x}{4^x\log 4}-\frac{1}{(\log4)^24^x}$$ $$
\implies\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x}{4^x\log 4}-\frac{1}{(\log 4)^24^x}\right)=\frac{x}{4^x}$$
if $f(x)=\frac{x}{4^x} $ and $g(x)=\sum_{x=0}^\infty \frac{x}{4^x}$ then:
$$g(x)=\frac{g'(x)}{\log 4}-\frac{1}{(\log4)^2}\sum_{x=0}^\infty\frac{1}{4^x}$$
Now it is a differential equation. Solve it.